# Can't acces localhost from Python app with webview and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, webview

I'm trying to build a dashboard with plotly and show it within the same python app. It uses the localhost to build the dashboard, but for some reason, if I try to show it in the same app I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

This is the code for the webview. If I put any other site, it opens correctly.

```
from tkinter import *
import webview
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
webview.create_window('LocalHost', 'http://127.0.0.1/')
webview.start()
```

And this is the example code I used for testing the dashboard. If I open the localhost in a browser it loads properly.

```
app = Dash(__name__)

# -- Import and clean data (importing csv into pandas)
# df = pd.read_csv("intro_bees.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coding-with-Adam/Dash-by-Plotly/master/Other/Dash_Introduction/intro_bees.csv")

df = df.groupby(['State', 'ANSI', 'Affected by', 'Year', 'state_code'])[['Pct of Colonies Impacted']].mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df[:5])

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Web Application Dashboards with Dash", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_year",
                 options=[
                     {"label": "2015", "value": 2015},
                     {"label": "2016", "value": 2016},
                     {"label": "2017", "value": 2017},
                     {"label": "2018", "value": 2018}],
                 multi=False,
                 value=2015,
                 style={'width': "40%"}
                 ),

    html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
    html.Br(),

    dcc.Graph(id='my_bee_map', figure={})

])


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect the Plotly graphs with Dash Components
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_container', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='my_bee_map', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='slct_year', component_property='value')]
)
def update_graph(option_slctd):
    print(option_slctd)
    print(type(option_slctd))

    container = "The year chosen by user was: {}".format(option_slctd)

    dff = df.copy()
    dff = dff[dff["Year"] == option_slctd]
    dff = dff[dff["Affected by"] == "Varroa_mites"]

    # Plotly Express
    fig = px.choropleth(
        data_frame=dff,
        locationmode='USA-states',
        locations='state_code',
        scope="usa",
        color='Pct of Colonies Impacted',
        hover_data=['State', 'Pct of Colonies Impacted'],
        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.YlOrRd,
        labels={'Pct of Colonies Impacted': '% of Bee Colonies'},
        template='plotly_dark'
    )

    # Plotly Graph Objects (GO)
    # fig = go.Figure(
    #     data=[go.Choropleth(
    #         locationmode='USA-states',
    #         locations=dff['state_code'],
    #         z=dff["Pct of Colonies Impacted"].astype(float),
    #         colorscale='Reds',
    #     )]
    # )
    #
    # fig.update_layout(
    #     title_text="Bees Affected by Mites in the USA",
    #     title_xanchor="center",
    #     title_font=dict(size=24),
    #     title_x=0.5,
    #     geo=dict(scope='usa'),
    # )

    return container, fig
```

I tried writing this lines

```
webview.create_window('LocalHost', 'http://127.0.0.1/')
webview.start()
```

right before

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

in case it was trying to acces the localhost before it was started, but it didn't work.

I also tried some solutions that I found for android, like changing the localhost for "http://10.0.2.2/", in case it was behaving like a virtual device, or even using my public ip adress, but didn't work either.

I'm launching the app from the same computer so I don't see why this wouldn't work. I thought about trying with websockets, but I feel that maybe there is an easier solution.

Comment: It's unclear. Post a [mre] with debugging details. How did you run the Dash(Flask) server and the client using the webview? You should run the client after the server finished initializing.

Comment: @relent95  I was trying to run the client after the server but according to the documentation, it seems that webview blocks the execution so the server never gets started. Now I created two different scripts for the server and the client, and one main script which runs these in different threads. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks

Comment: If you solved the problem, why not answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run the client after the server but according to the documentation, it seems that webview blocks the execution so the server never gets started. Now I created two different scripts for the server and the client, and one main script which runs these in different threads. It works fine now.

Comment: Please do not post new information related to the question as an answer. Instead, edit the question to include this new information.